# Angular HostBidding 'class.classname' makes no effect on the host

Tags: angular

I have component with following code

```js
import { Component, HostBinding, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-htest',
  templateUrl: './htest.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./htest.component.css'],
})
export class HtestComponent implements OnInit {
  
  @HostBinding('class.hosty') public hosty = true;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

The css:

```css
.htest {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.hosty {
  border: 5px dotted black;
}
```

There is class name `hosty` added to the `<app-htest>` but it has no effect at all, and devtols shows like there no class added...

I created [stackbits](https://angular-ivy-g2d8jy.stackblitz.io)

What am I missing?

Comment: According to your stackbits, your css is defined within the child component.
Move the .hosty { ... } rule into the app.component.css and it should work.

Comment: but if I move .hosty content to the :host{} in the same CSS file it will work. How could I define css class which will work on the component host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to set .hosty style from `HtestComponent` consumer component or you can define `.hosty` globally in `style.css`

**Or**

You need to use `:host` selector

```
:host.hosty {
  border: 5px dotted black;
}
```

Comment: Super, let me test a bit, and I will accept your answer! Ty